# Creating a user defined distribution in jags

Tags: r, jags

Normally, the model is generated based on some available distributions in JAGS, what if we need the parameters to be sampled from other specific distributions.

Is it possible to create a new distribution in JAGS

Comment: This answer to a semi-related question may be relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152966/3324348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you need the new distribution for.  If you want a new distribution to calculate the likelihood, you could use the [zeros or ones trick](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/Joseph/courses/common/Tricks.html).  If you need a new prior distribution, or something else that JAGS does not already have, you [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255986213_Extending_JAGS_A_tutorial_on_adding_custom_distributions_to_JAGS_with_a_diffusion_model_example) gives a good tutorial if you have the requisite C++ experience.