# Can JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler) deal with ordinary differential equations?

Tags: jags, winbugs

I searched about the `JAGS`'s manual and one post ([here in 2012](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/bbc3e34d/)) about the ordinary differential equation (ode). I was thinking `JAGS` can because it's similar to `WinBUGS` (which does it through `WBdiff` interface). However, if I let `JAGS` read in my ode code, it cannot even recognize the `D(y[...], t)` expression.

Can `JAGS` deal with ode? Maybe I missed a plug-in in `JAGS` like `WBdiff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While WinBUGS/OpenBUGS/JAGS have almost equivalent syntax/feature sets, there are a few differences between them:  one of these is that there is no ODE solver included as part of a standard JAGS installation.

However, JAGS is extensible using user-specified modules (like the plug-ins you mentioned), which provide new functions/distributions using C++ code that can then be used within JAGS when that module is loaded.  It would certainly be possible to implement an ODE this way using e.g. the ODE solvers included in the boost C++ library.  To do so you will need the following:

- Familiarity with C++
- Instructions for how to build a module for JAGS

I can't help you with the former, so this may be a dead-end for you if you have never used C++ before.  But there is a tutorial available for how to build a JAGS module:  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23959766/  This article shows how to build a standalone module, but if you are happy to accept the limitation of using JAGS from R (as most people do) then it is MUCH easier to build a JAGS module within an R package - you could follow code in the runjags package as an example https://cran.r-project.org/package=runjags

If you are thinking of trying to do this yourself then I could potentially help with a few pointers along the way. Of course, it is also possible that someone else has already done this, but if so then I am not aware of it.